# (projection)Lat Long issue in ESRI javascript api version 4.18 and above

Tags: javascript, esri, arcgis-js-api

Version 4.17 Projection is working fine, but if we use version 4.18 & above then, (lat & long) values going beyond the +/- 180.
Working Link: codepen.io/thanhtetaung/pen/NWGRZGJ  (version 4.15)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a change in behavior for the project() method. The longitudes are no longer "normalized" for project().

If you want the older ("normalized") behavior, you can use [webMercatorUtils.webMercatorToGeographic()](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-support-webMercatorUtils.html#webMercatorToGeographic) which includes a second property that allows you to either normalize or not.

In your codepen change from
`projection.project(view.extent, sr4326);`
to `webMercatorUtils.webMercatorToGeographic(view.extent, false);`.